# MS Access Group ID with parent and children

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a question regarding MS ACCESS. 
I have a table with multiple columns and about 1600 records.
The first two columns are sort of the names of the record.
They can be exactly the same or they can be different. However I need to group them with a GroupID. 
The grouping should give the same GroupID to the same family. a goes with b then all the names which goes with b are also in the same group as a and so on...
I try to illustrate it in the below table

```
GroupID      NAme1    Name2    Varia 
               aaa     aaa      lkj
              aaa      aaa      kjkjl
               aaa     bbb      lkjlkj
              ccc      ccc      kljlkjl
              ddd      ccc      kajlsjf
              bbb      eee      ljlkjlj
              eee      eee      lkjlkj
              fff      fff       kljl
              fff      ggg      jlkjlj
              iii      ccc      jlkjlkj
              jjj      jjj       alsjlfj
```

This would have the following ids

```
GroupID      NAme1    Name2    Varia
1             aaa      aaa      lkj
1             aaa      aaa      kjkjl
1             aaa      bbb      lkjlkj
2             ccc      ccc      kljlkjl
2             ddd      ccc      kajlsjf
1             bbb      eee      ljlkjlj
1             eee      eee      lkjlkj
3             fff      fff       kljl
3             fff      ggg      jlkjlj
2             iii      ccc      jlkjlkj
4             jjj      jjj       alsjlfj
```

Comment: Explain your grouping logic in more detail - not "and so on.." Does a go with b, c go with d, e go with f (and so on) - or does the grouping depend on the first non-match in Name2

Comment: the tow names to together as soon as they are in one record. As soon as a Name aaa is the same record as bbb they belong together. If later on a name yyy is in the same record as bbb then is also belongs to aaa's group

Comment: What happens when it belongs to two groups.  For example if you had a bbb ccc?  would this be 1 or 2?  Is there a precedence? or would this link make them all group 1?

Comment: This would make them all 1

Comment: Has anyone an idea.